# mod_jk not changes IP of hostname when occurs changing of IP on DNS

Tags: apache, dns, load-balancing, worker, mod-jk

In apache, the module mod_jk not changes IP of hostname when occurs changing of IP on DNS.

Version of apache:
Server version: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)
Server built:   Aug  2 2013 08:02:15

Version mod_jk: 1.2.37

Example:

workers.properties

```
worker.portalconsultoras_prd.type=ajp13
worker.portalconsultoras_prd.host=hostexample.com.br
worker.portalconsultoras_prd.port=8009
```

This configuration works fine.

But, when occurs change ip in the host name in DNS, the module md_jk starts fail to connect. Follow below the log of mod_jk:

[Wed Sep 18 12:00:33 2013] [5315:140659824723936] [info] jk_open_socket::jk_connect.c (627): connect to 107.xx.xx.220:8009 failed (errno=115)
[Wed Sep 18 12:00:33 2013] [5315:140659824723936] [info] ajp_connect_to_endpoint::jk_ajp_common.c (995): Failed opening socket to (107.xx.xxx.220:8009) (errno=115)
[Wed Sep 18 12:00:33 2013] [5315:140659824723936] [error] ajp_send_request::jk_ajp_common.c (1630): (portalconsultoras_prd) connecting to backend failed. Tomcat is probably not started or is listening on the wrong port (errno=115)

I would like a configuration of apache that avoid this problem.

Looking for the solutions in google, have turn on the "HostnameLookups", but is inefficient.

Thanks!